# Creating a dynamic array in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm new to programming with Lua so please forgive me my stupidity.
I'm trying to create a dynamic array using Lua for QBcore (FiveM), but I keep ending up with index (?) when I create the array.

[image: Code with index]

This makes the menu within the game not working (I think..).

The code I have is:

```
local mdtMenu = nil
RegisterNetEvent('qb-radialmenu:client:onRadialmenuOpen', function()
    if mdtMenu ~= nil then
        exports['qb-radialmenu']:RemoveOption(mdtMenu)
        mdtMenu = nil
    end
    
    local myData = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData()
    local myJob = myData.job
    local menuItems = createRadialJobExtrasMenu(myJob.onduty)
    
    if myJob.name == "ems" or myJob.name == "police" then
        mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption({
            menuItems
        }, mdtMenu)
    end
    
    print(QBCore.Debug(mdtMenu))
    --print(mdtMenu)
end)
```

The function used in above code:

```
function createRadialJobExtrasMenu(onduty)
    local extra_menuItems = {}
    local mdtMenu = {
        id = 'job_extras',
        title = 'Job Extras',
        icon = "square-plus",
        items = {
            open_mdt = {
                title = 'Open MDT menu',
                icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                type = 'command',
                event = "mdt",
                shouldClose = true
            },
            my_data = {
                title = 'My Data',
                icon = "person",
                type = 'command',
                event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                shouldClose = true
            },
            mdt_signonoff = {},
        }
    }
    
    if onduty then
        mdt_signonoff = {
            title = 'Sign Off (Duty)',
            icon = "circle-xmark",
            type = 'command',
            event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
            shouldClose = true
        }
    else
        mdt_signonoff = {
            title = 'Sign On (Duty)',
            icon = "check-to-slot",
            type = 'command',
            event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
            shouldClose = true
        }
    end
    
    table.insert(mdtMenu.items.mdt_signonoff, mdt_signonoff)
    
    return mdtMenu
end
```

The menu I expect when **on-duty** (note the third entry in `items:`):

```
local mdtMenu = nil
RegisterNetEvent('qb-radialmenu:client:onRadialmenuOpen', function()
    if mdtMenu ~= nil then
        exports['qb-radialmenu']:RemoveOption(mdtMenu)
        mdtMenu = nil
    end
    
    local myData = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData()
    local myJob = myData.job
    
    if myJob.name == "ems" or myJob.name == "police" then
            mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption({
                id = 'job_extras',
                title = 'Job Extras',
                icon = "square-plus",
                items = {
                    {
                        id = 'open_mdt',
                        title = 'Open MDT menu',
                        icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = "mdt",
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                    {
                        id = 'my_data',
                        title = 'My Data',
                        icon = "person",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                    {
                        id = 'mdt_signoff',
                        title = 'Sign Off (Duty)',
                        icon = "circle-xmark",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                }
            }, mdtMenu)
    end
end)
```

And when **off-duty** (note the third entry in `items:`):

```
local mdtMenu = nil
RegisterNetEvent('qb-radialmenu:client:onRadialmenuOpen', function()
    if mdtMenu ~= nil then
        exports['qb-radialmenu']:RemoveOption(mdtMenu)
        mdtMenu = nil
    end
    
    local myData = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData()
    local myJob = myData.job
    
    if myJob.name == "ems" or myJob.name == "police" then
            mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption({
                id = 'job_extras',
                title = 'Job Extras',
                icon = "square-plus",
                items = {
                    {
                        id = 'open_mdt',
                        title = 'Open MDT menu',
                        icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = "mdt",
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                    {
                        id = 'my_data',
                        title = 'My Data',
                        icon = "person",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                    {
                        id = 'mdt_signon',
                        title = 'Sign On (Duty)',
                        icon = "check-to-slot",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                }
            }, mdtMenu)
    end
end)
```

I hope my question makes any sence.

**Edit:** Changed the code as I assume that @Vlad means, but this still leaves me with 1 index (?) number.

**Edit2:** The only correct structure is like the code below:

```
local mdtMenu = nil
RegisterNetEvent('qb-radialmenu:client:onRadialmenuOpen', function()
    if mdtMenu ~= nil then
        exports['qb-radialmenu']:RemoveOption(mdtMenu)
        mdtMenu = nil
    end
    
    local myData = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData()
    local myJob = myData.job
    
    if myJob.name == "ems" or myJob.name == "police" then
        mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption({
            id = 'job_extras',
            title = 'Job Extras',
            icon = "square-plus",
            items = {
                {
                    id = 'open_mdt',
                    title = 'Open MDT menu',
                    icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                    type = 'command',
                    event = "mdt",
                    shouldClose = true
                },
                {
                    id = 'my_data',
                    title = 'My Data',
                    icon = "person",
                    type = 'command',
                    event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                    shouldClose = true
                },
            }
        }, mdtMenu)
    end
end)
```

But when I dynamically try to add a menu item with code below, I get an error.

```
if myJob.onduty then
        table.insert(mdtMenu.items, {id = 'mdt_signoff', title = 'Sign Off (Duty)', icon = "circle-xmark", type = 'command', event = 'myaddons-toggleduty', shouldClose = true})
    else
        table.insert(mdtMenu.items, {id = 'mdt_signon', title = 'Sign On (Duty)', icon = "check-to-slot", type = 'command', event = 'myaddons-toggleduty', shouldClose = true})
    end
```

The complete codeblock:

```
local mdtMenu = nil
RegisterNetEvent('qb-radialmenu:client:onRadialmenuOpen', function()
    if mdtMenu ~= nil then
        exports['qb-radialmenu']:RemoveOption(mdtMenu)
        mdtMenu = nil
    end
    
    local myData = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData()
    local myJob = myData.job
    
    if myJob.name == "ems" or myJob.name == "police" then
        mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption({
            id = 'job_extras',
            title = 'Job Extras',
            icon = "square-plus",
            items = {
                {
                    id = 'open_mdt',
                    title = 'Open MDT menu',
                    icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                    type = 'command',
                    event = "mdt",
                    shouldClose = true
                },
                {
                    id = 'my_data',
                    title = 'My Data',
                    icon = "person",
                    type = 'command',
                    event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                    shouldClose = true
                },
            }
        }, mdtMenu)
    end
    
    if myJob.onduty then
        table.insert(mdtMenu.items, {id = 'mdt_signoff', title = 'Sign Off (Duty)', icon = "circle-xmark", type = 'command', event = 'myaddons-toggleduty', shouldClose = true})
    else
        table.insert(mdtMenu.items, {id = 'mdt_signon', title = 'Sign On (Duty)', icon = "check-to-slot", type = 'command', event = 'myaddons-toggleduty', shouldClose = true})
    end
end)
```

The error I'm getting:

[image: Error]

It IS working with below code, but that means that I have to re-create the complete menu for each dynamic menu item, making the menu not-so-dynamic:

```
local mdtMenu = nil
RegisterNetEvent('qb-radialmenu:client:onRadialmenuOpen', function()
    if mdtMenu ~= nil then
        exports['qb-radialmenu']:RemoveOption(mdtMenu)
        mdtMenu = nil
    end
    
    local myData = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData()
    local myJob = myData.job
    
    if myJob.name == "ems" or myJob.name == "police" then
        if myJob.onduty then
            mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption({
                id = 'job_extras',
                title = 'Job Extras',
                icon = "square-plus",
                items = {
                    {
                        id = 'open_mdt',
                        title = 'Open MDT menu',
                        icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = "mdt",
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                    {
                        id = 'my_data',
                        title = 'My Data',
                        icon = "person",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                    {
                        id = 'mdt_signoff',
                        title = 'Sign Off (Duty)',
                        icon = "circle-xmark",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                }
            }, mdtMenu)
        else
            mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption({
                id = 'job_extras',
                title = 'Job Extras',
                icon = "square-plus",
                items = {
                    {
                        id = 'open_mdt',
                        title = 'Open MDT menu',
                        icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = "mdt",
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                    {
                        id = 'my_data',
                        title = 'My Data',
                        icon = "person",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                    {
                        id = 'mdt_signon',
                        title = 'Sign On (Duty)',
                        icon = "check-to-slot",
                        type = 'command',
                        event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
                        shouldClose = true
                    },
                }
            }, mdtMenu)
        end
    end
end)
```

**Edit3:** Below code seems to be working (thanks @dt192!!):

```
local mdtMenu = nil
RegisterNetEvent('qb-radialmenu:client:onRadialmenuOpen', function()
    if mdtMenu ~= nil then
        exports['qb-radialmenu']:RemoveOption(mdtMenu)
        mdtMenu = nil
    end
    
    local myData = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData()
    local myJob = myData.job
    
    if myJob.name == "ems" or myJob.name == "police" then
        local myTable = createRadialJobExtrasMenu(myJob.onduty)
        
        mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption(myTable, mdtMenu)
    end
end)

AddEventHandler('onResourceStop', function(resource)
    if mdtMenu ~= nil then
        exports['qb-radialmenu']:RemoveOption(mdtMenu)
        mdtMenu = nil
    end
end)
```

With the function:

```
function createRadialJobExtrasMenu(onduty)
    local tbl = {
        id = 'job_extras',
        title = 'Job Extras',
        icon = "square-plus",
        items = {
            {
                id = 'open_mdt',
                title = 'Open MDT menu',
                icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                type = 'command',
                event = "mdt",
                shouldClose = true
            },
            {
                id = 'my_data',
                title = 'My Data',
                icon = "person",
                type = 'command',
                event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                shouldClose = true
            },
            {
                id = 'mdt_signon',
                title = 'Sign On (Duty)',
                icon = "check-to-slot",
                type = 'command',
                event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
                shouldClose = true
            },
        }
    }

    if onduty then
        tbl.items[3].id = 'mdt_signoff'
        tbl.items[3].title = 'Sign Off (Duty)'
        tbl.items[3].icon = 'circle-xmark'
    end
    
    return tbl
end
```

Comment: seems like you should be doing `mdtMenu.items.mdt_signonoff = mdt_signonoff` instead of `table.insert(mdtMenu.items.mdt_signonoff, mdt_signonoff)`

Comment: @dt192 I seem to be getting a bit closer with this comment (eg. the number is now not being shown anymore), but the structure of the array does not seem to be correct as the menu is not showing in game. At the bottom of my question you see 2 correct structures (the on-duty and off-duty codes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something like this

```
    local tbl = {
        id = 'job_extras',
        title = 'Job Extras',
        icon = "square-plus",
        items = {
            {
                id = 'open_mdt',
                title = 'Open MDT menu',
                icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                type = 'command',
                event = "mdt",
                shouldClose = true
            },
            {
                id = 'my_data',
                title = 'My Data',
                icon = "person",
                type = 'command',
                event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                shouldClose = true
            },
            {
                id = 'mdt_signon',
                title = 'Sign On (Duty)',
                icon = "check-to-slot",
                type = 'command',
                event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
                shouldClose = true
            },
        }
    }

    if myJob.onduty then
        tbl.items[3].id = 'mdt_signoff'
        tbl.items[3].title = 'Sign Off (Duty)'
        tbl.items[3].icon = 'circle-xmark'
    end

    mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption(tbl, mdtMenu)
```

You could also just inline the checks like

```
    mdtMenu = exports['qb-radialmenu']:AddOption({
        id = 'job_extras',
        title = 'Job Extras',
        icon = "square-plus",
        items = {
            {
                id = 'open_mdt',
                title = 'Open MDT menu',
                icon = "tablet-screen-button",
                type = 'command',
                event = "mdt",
                shouldClose = true
            },
            {
                id = 'my_data',
                title = 'My Data',
                icon = "person",
                type = 'command',
                event = "myaddons-myinfo",
                shouldClose = true
            },
            {
                id = myJob.onduty and 'mdt_signoff' or 'mdt_signon',
                title = myJob.onduty and 'Sign Off (Duty)' or 'Sign On (Duty)',
                icon = myJob.onduty and 'circle-xmark' or 'check-to-slot',
                type = 'command',
                event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
                shouldClose = true
            },
        }
    }, mdtMenu)
```

or (not sure which version you are using at this point)

```
        mdtMenu.item.mdt_signonoff = {
            title = myJob.onduty and 'Sign Off (Duty)' or 'Sign On (Duty)',
            icon = myJob.onduty and 'circle-xmark' or 'check-to-slot',
            type = 'command',
            event = 'myaddons-toggleduty',
            shouldClose = true
        }
```

Comment: You are genius! This seems to be working fine! I've marked this as answer and added my new code to `Edit3` in my original post!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the array of arrays. But you're not giving the key values when storing the array holding the collection values in the the toplevel array holding all the collections. You've just stored the key as the item within the collection itself.

What it should look like:

```
items = {
  open_mdt = {
    collection1
  },
  my_data = {
    collection2
  }
}
```

This format works ok for strings without spaces only, and the general syntax working with numbers and arbitrary string would be:

```
items = {
  ["open mdt with spaces"] = {
    collection1
  },
  [37] = {
    collection2
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Vlad, thank you for the fast response! I'm sorry but I still don't completely understand. Could you please give a complete example using the code I need?